# calculating each day sum and last 7 days sum for max date to last 7 days and 14 days and 21 days sum in new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data set: which is daily sum. Based on this, how do i get last 7 days sum, 14 days sum and 21 days for each row in new columns.

I have tried to get last 7 days sum by using below query. but Its is giving cumulative sum instead of giving lookback to last 7 days.

```
select date,sum(amount) as amount,
   sum(sum(amount)) over (order by date desc rows between 6 preceding and current row) as amount_7days_ago from table1 group by date order by date desc;
```

from there on, not able to move forward with the idea. how can i achieve this in query?

[image]

Desired Result :

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: What is the desired output for the sample data?

Comment: Please add any clarifications directly into your question, not as comments

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can try to use self-join instead of window function.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT [DATE],
          SUM(amount) as amount
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY [DATE]
)
SELECT t2.[DATE],
       t2.amount as amount,
       sum(CASE WHEN t1.Date >= DATEADD(DAY,  -7, t2.[Date]) AND t1.Date < t2.Date THEN t1.amount ELSE 0 END)  as amount_7days_ago,
       sum(CASE WHEN t1.Date >= DATEADD(DAY,  -14, t2.[Date]) AND t1.Date < t2.Date THEN t1.amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_14days_ago,    
       Sum(CASE WHEN t1.Date >= DATEADD(DAY,  -21, t2.[Date]) AND t1.Date < t2.Date THEN t1.amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_14days_ago
FROM CTE t1
INNER JOIN CTE t2
ON t1.[DATE] <= t2.[Date]
GROUP BY t2.[DATE],t2.amount
ORDER BY t2.[DATE] DESC
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=87294440d1b6cd32aa2be349d306a5c6)

Comment: A person with your rep/experience should not be teaching or reinforcing the idea that the semicolon must precede "WITH" in a cte. That is only a poor kludge that encourages lazy coders to NOT use terminators everywhere - which you also reinforce.

Comment: Hey @SMor I think the code can represent the logic if OP has more questions I would edit my answer, why did you use the word `a poor kludge that encourages lazy coders` which might not be friendly??

Comment: @D-Shih, thanks for your reply. If I want to get exactly 7 days back sum of  max date how do we get it ??

Comment: Hi @Dileep I am not sure what you expect but I guess that can use `sum` or sum window function based on the result set by a subquery.

Comment: @Dileep Or could you edit your question and provide some sample data , and expected results for your extra question?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly - you want a rolling 7 days total, rolling 14 days and rolling 21 days.

If that is correct, then the problem you have is adding the group by and attempting to sum the windowing function.  And - you have the window incorrectly defined:

```
   With sampleData
     As (
 Select SampleDate      = dateadd(day, -row_number() Over(Order By @@spid) + 1, cast(getdate() As date))
      , SampleAmount    = cast(row_number() Over(Order By @@spid) * 1000 As money)
   From (Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0))       As t1(n)
  Cross Apply (Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) As t2(n)
        )
      , summaryData
     As (
 Select *
      , Last7Days       = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate desc
                                                        Rows Between Current Row And 6 Following)
      , Last14Days      = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate desc
                                                        Rows Between Current Row And 13 Following)
      , Last21Days      = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate desc
                                                        Rows Between Current Row And 20 Following)
   From sampleData                      sd
        )
 Select *
   From summaryData
  Where SampleDate >= eomonth(getdate(), -2);
```

We can order by the sample date descending - if we do that then we need a window from the current row to the 6/13/20 following rows.  Or - we switch to ascending and pull the 6 preceding rows to current row:

```
   With sampleData
     As (
 Select SampleDate      = dateadd(day, -row_number() Over(Order By @@spid) + 1, cast(getdate() As date))
      , SampleAmount    = cast(row_number() Over(Order By @@spid) * 1000 As money)
   From (Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0))       As t1(n)
  Cross Apply (Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) As t2(n)
        )
      , summaryData
     As (
 Select *
      , Last7Days       = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate
                                                        Rows Between 6 Preceding And Current Row)
      , Last14Days      = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate
                                                        Rows Between 13 Preceding And Current Row)
      , Last21Days      = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate
                                                        Rows Between 20 Preceding And Current Row)
   From sampleData                      sd
        )
 Select *
   From summaryData
  Where SampleDate >= eomonth(getdate(), -2);
```

Note: either way you look at this, you need to pull at least 21 days of data prior to the beginning of the range you want to display.  For example, if you want to show from current to beginning of this month you need to include at least 21 days in the summaryData:

```
Declare @startDate date = '2022-05-01';

   With sampleData
     As (
 Select SampleDate      = dateadd(day, -row_number() Over(Order By @@spid) + 1, cast(getdate() As date))
      , SampleAmount    = cast(row_number() Over(Order By @@spid) * 1000 As money)
   From (Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0))       As t1(n)
  Cross Apply (Values (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)) As t2(n)
        )
      , summaryData
     As (
 Select *
      , Last7Days       = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate
                                                        Rows Between 6 Preceding And Current Row)
      , Last14Days      = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate
                                                        Rows Between 13 Preceding And Current Row)
      , Last21Days      = sum(sd.SampleAmount) Over(Order By sd.SampleDate
                                                        Rows Between 20 Preceding And Current Row)
   From sampleData                      sd
  Where sd.SampleDate >= dateadd(day, -21, @startDate)
        )
 Select *
   From summaryData
  Where SampleDate >= @startDate;
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation. It was great for learning. Can u guide me on another thing like, how can I get the sum of exactly 7 days back to the date. The above query giving last 7 days sum. In the same way Now wanted to try, 7 days back 14 days back and 21 days back sum for first 15 days in descending order.

Comment: I don't understand your question - can you provide sample data and expected results?  It sounds like you want a rolling sum to current date and then just display the totals for today, 7 days ago, 14 days ago.  But really can't figure out your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I Got the answer for my self. Thanks for your help.

```
    ;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT [DATE],
          SUM(amount) as amount
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY [DATE]
)
SELECT t2.[DATE],
       t2.amount as amount,
       sum(CASE WHEN t1.Date = DATEADD(DAY,  -7, t2.[Date]) AND t1.Date < t2.Date THEN t1.amount ELSE 0 END)  as amount_7days_ago,
       sum(CASE WHEN t1.Date = DATEADD(DAY,  -14, t2.[Date]) AND t1.Date < t2.Date THEN t1.amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_14days_ago,    
       Sum(CASE WHEN t1.Date = DATEADD(DAY,  -21, t2.[Date]) AND t1.Date < t2.Date THEN t1.amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_14days_ago
FROM CTE t1
INNER JOIN CTE t2
ON t1.[DATE] <= t2.[Date]
GROUP BY t2.[DATE],t2.amount
ORDER BY t2.[DATE] DESC
```